# Oracle SQLDeveloper Command-Line (SQLcl) v19 run Script with Connection Timeout

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds

I am running SQLcl verion

```
SQL> version
Oracle SQLDeveloper Command-Line (SQLcl) version: 19.1.0.0
```

The following script works

```
echo @test/oracle_sql_cl/read_schema.sql | sql -S ${USER}/${PASSWORD}@${TNS_NAME}
```

A timeout parameter is needed.

Here are some examples tired but without success

```
echo @test/oracle_sql_cl/read_schema.sql | sql -S -t 5 ${USER}/${PASSWORD}@${TNS_NAME}
```

The above command fails.

Also updated the TNS_NAME var like so

```
export TNS_NAME="(DESCRIPTION=(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(RETRY_COUNT=1)(RETRY_DELAY=1)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=...
```

But connection still reties the connecion.

Any ideas would be much appreciated :~)

## Solution

Update the connection string to include

```
export TNS_NAME="(DESCRIPTION=(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=2)...
```

And modify the invocation to

```
echo @test/oracle_sql_cl/read_schema.sql | sql -S ${USER}/${PASSWORD}@${TNS_NAME}
```

Comment: "The above command fails." This is not a constructive statement as we cannot see the failing command (it's a call to a script and you do not include the script) and you do not tell us **HOW** it fails. If the script takes 10 minutes to run and you've told it to time-out after 5 minutes then of course it is going to timeout. Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with a complete description of the problem including the failing script and the complete error messages.

Comment: On a side note, it is considered *extremely* bad security practice to place user credentials into environment variables such as you are doing in your example. When the process is executed, the value of the variable is placed into the command line and is then visible to literally *any* user on the system using the `ps` command.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JDBC URL in your connect string.

With timeout set to 10 milliseconds it fails.

With timeout set to 1000 milliseconds it works.

```
SQL> connect system/oracle@jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10ms)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(HOST=server.com)(PORT=2213)(PROTOCOL=tcp)))(CONNECT_DATA=(S
ERVICE_NAME=DB213P)))
  USER          = system
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10ms)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(HOST=server.com)(PORT=2213)(PROTOCOL=tcp)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DB213P)))
  Error Message = IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=MES6gto9SkeXW93/WnHZ6A==)

SQL> connect system/oracle@jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=1000ms)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(HOST=server.com)(PORT=2213)(PROTOCOL=tcp)))(CONNECT_DATA=
(SERVICE_NAME=DB213P)))
Connected.
SQL>
```

This JDBC property **CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT** is defined/documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html).